# Accessing hashes with slash separated keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, hash

Suppose I have the following hash in one of my models named Company.

```
FIELDS = {
    TEAM: {
        'num_founders': 'Number of Founders',
        'num_employees': 'Number of Employees',
        'founders': {
            'person_info': {
                'full_name': 'Full Name',
                'first_name': 'First Name',
                'last_name': 'Last Name',
                'location': 'Location',
                'gender': 'Gender',
                'biography': 'Biography',
                'num_articles': 'Number of Articles'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I have a action in my application controller which renders this hash as json:

```
def field_names
    module_name = params[:module]
    category = params[:category]

    case module_name
    when 'company'
      render json: Company::FIELDS[category.to_sym].to_json
    end
end
```

So now if I open `localhost:3000/field_names/company/TEAM` I'd get the json. But the problem I'm now facing is I need to get the sub hash of this hash too. Like I want to `/field_names/company/TEAM/founders/person_info` and get the respective object.

To begin with I'd split the url by slashes to get the keys. Im unable to figure out how would I use those strings to access the hash.

If I define the route like `get '/field_names/:query', to: 'application#field_names`

And If I hit `localhost:3000/field_names/company/TEAM/founders`
The action should render `Company::FIELDS[:TEAM]["founders"]` object which would be

```
'person_info': {
    'full_name': 'Full Name',
    'first_name': 'First Name',
    'last_name': 'Last Name',
    'location': 'Location',
    'gender': 'Gender',
    'biography': 'Biography',
    'num_articles': 'Number of Articles'
}
```

For this my action should do something like:

```
def field_names
    query = params[:query]
    keys = query.split("/")
    #keys.first::FIELDS[key2][key3]... .to_json
end
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
fields = {
  TEAM: {
    'num_founders': 'Number of Founders',
    'num_employees': 'Number of Employees',
    'founders': {
      'person_info': {
        'full_name': 'Full Name',
        'first_name': 'First Name',
        'last_name': 'Last Name',
        'location': 'Location',
        'gender': 'Gender',
        'biography': 'Biography',
        'num_articles': 'Number of Articles'
      }
    }
  }
}.with_indifferent_access


'TEAM/founders'.split('/').each do |key|
  fields = fields[key]
end

puts fields

=> {"person_info"=>{"full_name"=>"Full Name", "first_name"=>"First Name", "last_name"=>"Last Name", "location"=>"Location", "gender"=>"Gender", "biography"=>"Biography", "num_articles"=>"Number of Articles"}}
```

Just for console, I changed `FIELDS` to `fields` (SHOUTING_CASE is usually reserved for constants, fwiw). And, I used `with_indifferent_access` because your nested hashes use both `strings` and `symbols` as keys.

If you want that `person_info`, then:

```
fields = {
  TEAM: {
    'num_founders': 'Number of Founders',
    'num_employees': 'Number of Employees',
    'founders': {
      'person_info': {
        'full_name': 'Full Name',
        'first_name': 'First Name',
        'last_name': 'Last Name',
        'location': 'Location',
        'gender': 'Gender',
        'biography': 'Biography',
        'num_articles': 'Number of Articles'
      }
    }
  }
}.with_indifferent_access

'TEAM/founders/person_info'.split('/').each do |key|
  fields = fields[key]
end

puts fields    

=> {"full_name"=>"Full Name", "first_name"=>"First Name", "last_name"=>"Last Name", "location"=>"Location", "gender"=>"Gender", "biography"=>"Biography", "num_articles"=>"Number of Articles"}
```

You probably want to put some `try` in there in case the url is malformed.

Also, you could abstract and simplify that bit where you go:

```
case module_name
when 'company'
  render json: Company::FIELDS[category.to_sym].to_json
end
```

Assuming you have (in `routes.rb`):

```
get '/field_names/:query'
```

And you hit:

```
localhost:3000/field_names/company/TEAM/founders
```

Then your params should include:

```
{query: 'company/TEAM/founders'}
```

In which case you do something like:

```
def field_names
  query_split = params[:query].split

  module_name = query_split.shift.camelize
  fields = "#{module_name}::FIELDS".constantize.clone.with_indifferent_access
  query_split.each{|key| fields = fields[key]}
  render json: fields

end
```

You don't have to put `to_json` at the end of your hash, btw.

Answer (score 1):

It's a routing problem in your project. Actually, you should have a route to retrieve these fieldnames, like:

```
get 'field_names' => 'controller#action'
```

then, you can pass any parameters on your URL.
Eg.

```
/field_names?company=TEAM&attribute=founders
```

Than, those attributes would be available in your controller as

```
params[:company]
params[:attribute]
```

and so you can render only the attributes you want

Comment: what if i want the person_info object too? Thats inside the founders obj

Comment: Then add in the ID for the person info. Then you can do PersonInfo.find(params[:person_info_id], /field_names?person_info_id=14

Comment: personinfo is not a model actually. its one of the nested object